# openpyxl appending rows with style

Tags: openpyxl

I am appending rows to openpyxl and I want to do that with different styles

```
for i, row in enumerate(mydata):
    ws.append(row)
    if (my_logic_is_true):
        ws.row_dimensions[(i+1)].fill = redFill
        ws.row_dimensions[(i+1)].font = Font(bold=True)
    else:
        ws.row_dimensions[(i+1)].fill = greenFill
```

Problem: Instead of applying the style on the whole row, it applies the style (fill and bold) to all the cells of the row after the last written cell for the row.

Say for example, for each row, I am writing three cells, then the style would be applied to 4th cell onwards.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the documentation: row and column styles are hints to apply the formats for **future** cells. If you want to style a whole or column then you will have to apply the styles to all relevant cells yourself.